# Prevent screen burn while using Split View

Tags: spaces, mission-control, split-view

I use a display that is sensitive to [screen burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in). The content of my screen changes frequently enough, except for one thing. The bar separates two application windows when using [Split View](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948). I started moving the black bar a bit to the left and to the right manually, but I forget to do this all the time.

[image: Spaces in Mission Control]

Does anybody know how to still use Split View, while preventing screen burn at the same time?

Comment: Since the separator is black and the handle is dark gray, I'd tend to think it doesn't contribute much to screen burn...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see a black bar burned in when I don't move the bar around.

Comment: @jaume Just a bit of proof that it can actually happen with those black bars: https://files.adriaan.io/images/screen-burn.png